# How to prevent textLabel to be truncated when using UITableViewCellStyleValue1?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, textlabel

When using UITableViewCell with UITableViewCellStyleValue1 style the textLabel.text is being truncated when detailTextLabel is pretty long.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

cell.textLabel.text = @"Publisher";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"This Is A Very Long String";
```

So the question is how to force "Publisher" to be displayed without being truncated regarldess length of detailTextLabel?

P.S. I am new in this community so I couldn't post images which could clarify better the problem. Sorry for that...

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `[cell.detailTextLabel setNumberOfLines:0];`
Maybe it works.

Comment: This is a great solution, the only thing is it changes the position of the textLabel

Answer (score 0):

If you're actively changing the text of a cell then it may be truncated because the label is not being expanded despite having lots of room. You can call `[cell setNeedsLayout]` after changing the text to fix that particular issue.